# prove that if every induced subgraph of G is connected,then G is the complete graph Kn

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph of order n

prove that if every induced subgraph of G is connected,then G is the complete graph  Kn

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to prove a more general statement. Try this one: if every induced subgraph of $G$ ***of order two*** is connected, then $G$ is a complete graph.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $G$ is not $K_n$, there must be two distinct vertices, $u$ and $v$, of $G$ such that $uv$ is not an edge of $G$.

Comment: i need answer for my question ....

Comment: @Mohammed: I gave you a very big hint. Use $u$ and $v$ to find an induced subgraph that isn't connected.